# setInterval not repeating inside event listener

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to make a snake game using JavaScript and cannot get setInterval to repeatedly call a function:

```
class Game {

  constructor(){
    this.xPosition = 0
    this.yPosition = 0
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.drawSquare(0,0);
  }

  drawSquare(x,y){
    this.xPosition += x
    this.yPosition += y;
    if (this.xPosition < 0){
      this.xPosition = 600;
    }
    else if (this.xPosition > 600){
      this.xPosition = 0;
    }
    if (this.yPosition < 0){
      this.yPosition = 600;
    }
    else if (this.yPosition > 600){
      this.yPosition = 0;
    }
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    this.ctx.fillRect(this.xPosition,this.yPosition,60,60);
  }
  moveUp(){
    this.drawSquare(0,-60);
  }
}

var game = new Game();

//add EventListener for keyboard
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  switch (e.key){
    case 'w':
      setInterval(game.moveUp,1000);
      break;
  }
});
```

When I run "setInterval(game.moveUp,1000)", I come across a TypeError: this.drawSquare is not a function. This is confusing me since I clearly defined the function up top, and when I run game.moveUp() inside the switch case without setInterval the error disappears.

Comment: Remove the `()` on the end of the function so that it is not immediately invoked. It should be `setInterval(game.moveUp, 1000);`...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) accepts a function and `game.moveUp()` is a function call  <sup>1</sup>  , so the correct usage is:

```
setInterval(game.moveUp, 1000);
```

<sup>1</sup>  *That does not return another function.*

---

Update: This addresses concerns that have been raised after initial question was answered.

You need to ensure that `this` is bound too. Please see corrected code below (I've made it move down so you can actually see the movement) and research more about *binding this in JavaScript.*

```js
class Game {

  constructor(){
    this.xPosition = 0
    this.yPosition = 0
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.drawSquare(0,0);
  }

  drawSquare(x,y){
    this.xPosition += x
    this.yPosition += y;
    if (this.xPosition < 0){
      this.xPosition = 600;
    }
    else if (this.xPosition > 600){
      this.xPosition = 0;
    }
    if (this.yPosition < 0){
      this.yPosition = 600;
    }
    else if (this.yPosition > 600){
      this.yPosition = 0;
    }
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    this.ctx.fillRect(this.xPosition,this.yPosition,60,60);
  }
  moveUp(){
    console.log('move up');
    this.drawSquare(0, 60);
  }
}

var game = new Game();

//add EventListener for keyboard
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  switch (e.key){
    case 'w':
      setInterval(game.moveUp.bind(game) ,1000);
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried to do as you said but I come across another problem, I updated my original post illustrating the new problem. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer, but please don't change it like that with completely different scope, but rather post a new question